# Does this ODE result for hold for ODEs in the complex plane as well?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to make use of a theorem that gives a result on the dependence on the initial condition for an IVP. However, the statement is formulated for $\mathbb{R}^n$ while I am working in $\mathbb{C}$. I know that the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for differential equations in $\mathbb{C}$ is proved similarly as in the classic proof, but I am not sure if that is the case for this as well.

The theorem I have is this:

Suppose that $f \in C^k(U, \mathbb{R^n})$, where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Then around each point $(x_0, t_0) \in U$ we can find an open set $I \times B \subseteq U$ such that $\phi(t,x) \in C^k(I \times B,\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $\phi$ is the solution of our IVP.

Can I make this theorem hold for analytic $f$ and with $\mathbb{C}$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^n$? The proof is rather technical and long

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^n$, so there shouldn't be any big problems.

Comment: In what sense are they isomorphic? As vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. We can carry over rules for vector addition into the complex plane.